# Is there a typescript library with main lombok-style decorators?

Tags: typescript

I really like some patterns made much easier by the [Lombok library](https://projectlombok.org/). Annotations like [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) and [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) will generate methods for me that I almost always want on certain kinds of objects.

I'd like to use these patterns in typescript as well, but it's a bit of a pain to write all this code which could be done by a decorator. Are there any well-known, supported libraries for this? And if not, is there a reason (such as these patterns not being as necessary in typescript for whatever reason)?

I found the [builder-pattern npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/builder-pattern), which looks great, but I'm greedy and am wondering if there is a bigger, more widely used typescript library with more of these common patterns built in and exposed through decorators.